# Free Content Management System as backend

Tags: content-management-system

I have a website built (Java/J2EE), and now I want to store documents in abundance.
I want my website to use the CMS system, I do not want the CMS system to make a website.
Sort of use CMS as a database, and have my current website be a front end to the docs.
Any product recommendations, given I need to integrate it with an existing website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very depends on your website.
I hope [opensourcecms](http://php.opensourcecms.com/) help you to choose.